# Android Studio gradle build stuck at app:processDebugResources

Tags: android, gradle, build

I'm on Windows. I created a new project on Android Studio for Marshmallow at least.
The only thing I've done so far is generating the main activity which is a tabbed activity with view pager. Also, you should know that this project is a private git repo that I cloned.

I'm working on this project with another developer and the project is perfectly working on his side.

**The problem is:**

When I try to launch the app (wether it is a virtual device or my real phone), the gradle build gets stuck at the app:processDebugResources step. I waited more than an hour and nothing happened. Moreover, when I want to cancel the gradle build, it doesn't respond and I have to kill Android Studio process. Then I restart Android Studio and I have to kill a gradle process that prevents the initial gradle build (at Android Studio startup) from working.

*The crazy thing is that I was able to launch the app before. I even installed it on my phone!*

**What I've tried so far:**

- Do what stackoverflow was giving as solutions like tick the offline mode in the settings
- Create a new project --> It doesn't change anything
- Reinstall Android Studio --> It doesn't change anything
- Deactivating Avast antivirus
- Invalidate cache/restart + Clean + rebuild (the rebuild gets stuck like when I try to launch the app)
- And maybe other solutions that I forgot...

It's getting very annoying as it's making me lose days of development.

If you have any more solutions, or if you think I should try again some of the previous solutions, help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did several things:

- Install NDK
- Change JDK from embedded one to Jdk 8
- Redownload SDK i was using (6,7,8)

And now the problem is solved ! I have no idea which of these things made the tricks but I'm happy ! It may be useful to someone else one day.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I faced the same problem during the last few days and since i got crazy I hope I can help someone else out there.

After many hours of troubleshooting I found that the Java Platform SE binary executable goes in "suspended mode" in Windows 10, preventing Android Studio from compiling (it hangs at app:processDebugResources).

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAPvO.png)

Killing the suspended process and recompiling the project works just fine... until Java gets suspended again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your gradle version is not compatible with it. Try again with latest version of gradle in your project.

Comment: My gradle version is 4.1 and my Android plugin version is 3.0.0